# Split string by date time values into substrings

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string of the type

> 2014-02-19 16:21:46,139 ERROR  queue.TaskQueueEngine  - failed to
>   resolve task queue entry for first-level failure detection task
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection timed
>   out: connect 2014-02-19 16:35:48,247 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1]
>   cluster.ClusterServiceImpl  - unexpected error when trying to update
>   LastCheckinTime java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException:
>   Connection timed out: connect

....

I am trying to split it into substrings by date time values for eg.

> log[0]=2014-02-19 16:21:46,139 ERROR  queue.TaskQueueEngine  - failed
>   to resolve task queue entry for first-level failure detection task
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection timed
>   out: connect
>
> log[1]=2014-02-19 16:35:48,247 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1]
>   cluster.ClusterServiceImpl  - unexpected error when trying to update
>   LastCheckinTime java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException:
>   Connection timed out: connect

I am using the following command

```
string exLogs = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\orion.log");
string[] messages = Regex.Split(exLogs,] @"^([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-
         ([0-3][0-9])\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])");
```

However instead of giving me substrings it is giving me

```
log[0]=2014
log[1]=02
```

etc.
What could I be doing wrong.
Thanks any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i can see a comma after every date and time in your sample data if that is the case you can split it using comma and do some simple tweaks to get the required output.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi - that assumes that the error log text after the date never contains a comma. I'd be very weary to assume that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `^` form start of matcher.

in regex ***`^`*** means *The match must start at the beginning of the string or line.*

try this:

```
string[] messages = Regex.Split(exLogs,
    "([0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\\s(?:[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])");
```

Comment: The `|` there means your regex is very different from what is intended. Use a non-capturing paren instead.

Comment: Thanks this regex worked.I am yet to get my head over regular expressions and lifted the regex up from regexlibrary without really understanding what is meant.The discussion above helped me get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will be easier in two parts:

First get the split:

```
string[] dateAndTime = tex.Split(' ');
```

Then get the date and time each in his own string]:

```
string[] date = dateAndTime[0].Split('-');
string[] time = dateAndTime[1].Split(':');
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

A few things are happening here - you are using many capturing parens where you do not need to - these are causing the results of each capturing paren to be returned as a separate result. Most of these are not needed - the only one needed is the one used for hours matches and it can be changed into a non capturing paren.

Second - you are anchoring the regex to the the start of the line (`^`) - this means it will never match the date in the middle of the log.

Third - your use of a `\s` will not match multiple spaces - you should be using `\s+`.

Fourth - split will not return the value split on.

I removed most of the capturing parens, added a no-capture for the hour, removed the start anchor, and changed the space matcher to `\s+`.

I wrapped the whole thing in a paren to return the date value as well:

```
@"([0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\s+(?:[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])"
```

This returns an array, where the first item is empty (what is before the first date), then the date, then the log error, then a date, then a log error.